# Argument of type 'Node' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CustomElement'. ts(2345)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js, tsx

I am working on a real time collaborative text block editor via liveblocks.

My VSCode is throwing the following errors in my Editor.tsx file.

What would you recommend to fix this error?

```
Error:


Argument of type 'Node' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CustomElement'.

Type 'BaseEditor & ReactEditor' is not assignable to type 'CustomElement'.

Type 'BaseEditor & ReactEditor' is not assignable to type 'FigmaElement'.

Property 'id' is missing in type 'BaseEditor & ReactEditor' but required in type 'BlockElement'.

types.ts\[Ln 55, Col 3\] 'id' is declared here.
```

```
function isNodeWithId(editor: Editor, id: string) {
  return (node: Node) => Editor.isBlock(editor, node) && node.id === id;
}

export default function App() {
  const editor = useEditor();

  const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const activeElement = editor.children.find(
    (x) => "id" in x && x.id === activeId
  ) as CustomElement | undefined;
```

Here is the section from "types.ts[Ln 55, Col 3] 'id' is declared here."

```
export type TextBlock =
  | BlockType.Title
  | BlockType.H1
  | BlockType.H2
  | BlockType.H3
  | BlockType.Paragraph
  | BlockType.BulletedList
  | BlockType.ToDo;

export type BlockElement = {
  id: string;
  children: CustomText[];
  createdBy?: number;
};
```

I am still fairly new to TS / React so if more context is needed please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have the issue of a type mismatch.  Without a bit more context, it is hard to confirm, but you could try the following:

```
function isNodeWithId(editor: Editor, id: string) {
  return (node: Node): node is BlockElement => 
    Editor.isBlock(editor, node) && node.id === id;
}

export default function App() {
  const editor = useEditor();

  const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const activeElement = editor.children.find(
    (x): x is BlockElement => "id" in x && x.id === activeId
  );
}
```

so specifying the node element has the type BlockElement

Could you let me know if this resolves for you?  If it doesn't, I'm happy to try to provide additional support in our [discord channel](https://discordapp.com/channels/913109211746009108/913158542565994606).